# How many patterns could $n$ connected bricks form?

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, tiling

As shown below is a floor pattern with identical  bricks, each with width of 1 unit and length of 2 units.

[image]

Picking $n$ bricks from the floor , how many kinds of patterns could they form, if all of them shall be connected? Two bricks are called *connected* if they share at least 1 unit length of side.

Rotating of the same shape are considered the same; while mirroring is not

Comment: Are rotations of the same shape to be considered the same shape?  How about reflections?

Comment: Are you allowed holes?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert let’s allow rotation but not mirroring

Comment: @Henry yeah so long as all connected I suppose holes are fine

Comment: Is a pattern different from another based only on its overall shape, or do internal brick edges matter also?

Comment: It appears this grid is equivalent to a hexagonal grid where we distinguish two types of tiles.

Comment: @Joffan overall shape pls

Comment: @Vepir it’s more than hexagon

Comment: @athos It's just [hexagon (coordinates)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Zh2.png), no more, no less.

Comment: @Vepir it's more than that. for example, in hexagon grid, all triangles are the same, however, in the brick pattern there are two kinds of triangles, one rotates clockwise, the other anticlockwise.

Comment: @athos That is true, hence why I mentioned that we distinguish two types of tiles. That is, you can count all the paths on the hexagonal grid and then subtract the rotated duplicates (taking into account the two distinct types of tiles).

Comment: @Vepir Hexagon grid is still useful, I was thinking might to use coloured hexagon grid.. still checking..

Comment: @athos: I'm fairly certain that a closed form will not be achievable. Have you considered writing a program to get results for small values of $n$?